# No module named 'scipy' in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have installed scipy on windows with conda.

I'm using Python version 3.6.1

This is the error i recieve in pycharm that the scipy module is not found:
[image]

I have also installed the wheel file with pip install and receives the following:

[image]

So if the scipy is installed correctly why is pycharm complaining?

Answer (score 3):

You need to install scipy package in PyCharm. Check out this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html) for official tutorial on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to install scipy from within PyCharm, you can add the path of the scipy installation to the interpreter. Follow [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-reloading-interpreter-paths.html) tutorial.